# Emulator in Android Studio starts but doesn't turn on

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-2.3

My Android Studio version is 2.3.3. I downloaded it about a two weeks ago. I have installed HAXM and I'm am using the recommended API 26 O x86 for my emulator. When I start the emulator, it appears but does not load, i.e., show the 'ANDROID' title written on screen and turn on. What I get is just a black screen. It is very important for me because I am working on a project and I can't use a physical smartphone all the time for debugging.

Thanks in advance.

I did check a lot of answers to different questions related to my question but I did not find any solutions.

This is my screen:

[image: As I said, I just get a black screen.]

Comment: Yes i was having same issue. i downgraded the emulator version to 26.0.3 and it is working fine.

Comment: it will take some time to load android in your emulator based on your hardware capacity.

Comment: @Gaurav I kept it on for about 20 minutes but unfortunately, nothing happened

Comment: @Jaymin Can you tell me how?

Comment: @KevalPithadiya As  Jaymin said just try with downgrade the current OS version. Open your virtual device manager then click on Edit and change current API level.

Comment: @Gaurav Ok, alright. I thought Jaymin meant to change the version of my EMULATOR. Well anyways, I'm using the recommended API version and I don't think that could be an issue.

Comment: Even if it turns on.. it would be slow... try Genymotion. Fast.

Answer (score 35):

I just encountered the same issue and was able to resolve by performing a Cold Reboot.

In Android Studio, do the following:

1. Toolbar > Tools > AVD Manager
2. Click the Edit dropdown > Coldboot Now

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Much simpler than installing some other emulator

Comment: Agree, this should be accepted as an answer.

Comment: This is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem as the OP after clicking the power button on the emulator. The emulator turned off, but I couldn't turn it back on again - despite trying long clicks on the power button and restarting the emulator.

My solution was to close the emulator, then going into **AVD Manager** in Android Studio and selecting the **Wipe Data** option for this emulator.

When I then restarted the emulator, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-Installing your HAXM, If you already done with it. Then i will suggest you to go with GenyMotion or Bluestacks Virtual devices for testing the Application because android emulator is very slow as compare to these devices:

[BlueStack](https://www.bluestacks.com/)

OR

[Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download)

Comment: Okay, I'll try it out.

Comment: I have already tried bluestacks sometime ago and I'm not happy with its performance. But Genymotion might turn out to be a good alternative to traditional android emulator.

Comment: I had genymotion and yes your are right Its much more better than Bluestack! So if reinstalling HAXM not solving your problem, then yes! go for genymotion. You will like it!

Comment: Well, I already had tried re-installing HAXM. So, I had none other option then going for Genymotion.

Comment: did you try to install another emulator like if you installed NExus device then did you try device like samsung?

Comment: Can explain more briefly please?

Comment: I mean create New Virtual device Like create device like Galaxy nexus! or another device.

Comment: Because i had the same problem! I then created new virtual device and it works perfectly..dont know why.. but it works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156799/discussion-between-kevalpithadiya-and-uzair-qaiser).

Comment: Better answer below. The solution to fix Android Emulator shouldn't be "install different emulator software"